# How to support JSON schema oneOf definition using JAXB?

Tags: json, jaxb, jsonschema

I was given a JSON schema which uses "oneOf" like below, is there a way to define XSD to generate the JAXB objects, which can support this "oneOf" definition of JSON data marshalling and demarshalling?  I am using Jackson.

```
"Source": {
        "description": "Indicates the source.",
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "Source1": {
                        "description": "Indicates the source 1.",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "Source2": {
                        "description": "Indicates the source 2",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "field1": {
                                "description": "filed 1 for source 1",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "field2": {
                                "description": "field 2 for source 2",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
       ]
   }
```